# How to make these three divs inside a containing div float correctly in chrome - third div is lower than the first two

Tags: css

Here is the jfiddle I created to demonstrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/ew3nD/

Please edit the code and do not create a new example from scratch unless it has the same structure as my example.

Comment: Hard to help when it isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish. What is meant by "float correctly"?

Comment: In chrome the three divs aren't horizontal, the third div is lower than the first two. Please view example in chrome to see this.

Comment: The order of your markup is problematic if you want all the elements floated. Given that order, you'll need to use positioning for the third element: http://jsfiddle.net/ew3nD/2/

Comment: Hmm thanks for the reply but I wanted to accomplish this using floats if possible. The containing div of the three divs is already positioned absolutely in my code, for example.

Comment: You'll need to change the order of your elements if you want just floats: http://jsfiddle.net/ew3nD/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ew3nD/5/

HTML

```
<div class="paging-toolbar">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.paging-toolbar {
    width: 100%;
}
.paging-toolbar div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
#right
{
    float: right;
    background:#f00;
}
#left
{
    float: left;
    background:#f00;
}
#center
{
    background:#f00;
    margin: 0 auto;
}​
```

(I clean up your code a bit)

Answer (score 0):

Place your right div, first above left and centre.

```
    <div id="right" style="height:100px; width:100px">

</div>

    <div id="left" style="height:100px; width:100px">

</div>

    <div id="center" style="height:100px; width:100px">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, instead of relying on `margin: 0 auto` and floats, you can use `position: absolute`. In case the width of the elements change you just change the `margin-left` in `.b2`:

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/haGeC/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box b1"></div>
    <div class="box b2"></div>
    <div class="box b3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.b1, .b2, .b3 {
    position: absolute;
}
.b2 {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* width 100/2 */
}
.b1 { left: 0; }
.b3 { right: 0; }
```